# ExtJS 4 making more dynamic filter based on change selection

Tags: php, extjs

I'm having really hard time to understand the different kind of filters and when and how to use them so I've decided to start from the very begining and increase the level of difficulty slowly. I tried the most simple filter which i got from the ExtJS 4 documentation, I have a controller, a stroe, a model and a view, and I use CodeIgnaiter for my backend. Because I want to go bottom up what I've done is this:

```
Ext.define('ABC.store.FilterRecordsByForm', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'ABC.model.FormRecord',

    autoLoad: true,
//  autoSync: true,
//  remoteFilter: true,
//  remoteSort: false,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        actionMethods: 'POST',
        api: {
         read:  g_settings.baseUrl + 'index.php/record/getRecordsListByForms'


        },
        reader :{
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    },

        filters: [
        {
            property: 'procedure_id',
            value   : 3
        }
    ]

});
```

So here I just use the example from ExtJS 4 documentation and hardcoded my filter in the stroe. So far so good. It works as expected. But now I want to make my `value` field to get a variable as a value and reload the filter every time the value is of the `vlue` field is changed. I'm a littile  bit confused which exact implementation of Ext filter to use here and where. I think I should place it in the controller, but have no clue how to change my filter to respond on the new value it gets, and do I have to make changes on my server side code or I can make it only on the client side?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your store has remoteFiler set to true you can just do something like:

```
store.clearFilter();
store.filter('procedure_id', new_value);
```

This would cause store to reload it content according to the new filter.

Comment: Hello, Sha, glad to see you. What I've done by now is :`comboBoxFilterSt.clearFilter(true);
   comboBoxFilterSt.filter({
    filterFn: function(item) { 
     return item.get('category_id') == sel.raw.categoryId;
    }
   })`; and if I exclude a few little problems it works as needed. The problem is that I prefer remote sorting instead, so I tried this: comboBoxFilterSt.filters.clear();
   comboBoxFilterSt.filters.add(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',... and your suggetsion is a third option, could you point me the difference b/w Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter and what you\ve proposed?

Comment: You want the filter be remote. So basically you don't need any JS logic in filter, you just need filter be passed as an additional parameter to your query.

Comment: Yeah, this is what should my filtering looks like in the end, but i try to understand the steps to achieving it, so could you be more specific where and how I should use the code you wrote at your comment.In a handler, in a listener or to fire and event...

Comment: Whenever you need to filter the store. You might want to look at the `filter()` method implementation in ExtJs. It will be very clear how it supports different types of arguments (basically it can handle objects, array or just 'fieldname', 'valuename' pairs)